# Getting compile-time constant offsetof of base class in multiple-inheritance

Tags: c++

Look at this example:

```
struct s77 {
    char d[77];
};

struct s1 {
    char d;
};

struct Foo: s77, s1 {
};

struct Off {
    static const int v = std::size_t(static_cast<s1*>(static_cast<Foo*>(nullptr)+1)) - std::size_t(static_cast<Foo*>(nullptr)+1);
};
```

This code tries to put the offset of `s1` in `Foo` into `Off::v`. This code compiles with GCC/clang (without any warnings), but fails to compile with VS2015/VS2017 (error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant)

Which compiler is correct?

Can I achieve this functionality in a standard conformant way? If it is not possible, is it possible to create a working solution which works with VS2015/VS2017? I'm willing to accept any working solution, even which has undefined behavior according to the standard (but happens to work with VS2015 and VS2017). `Off::v` must be a compile time constant.

---

My original problem is this: I have an own implementation of `tuple`, which is implemented with multiple inheritance (like clang's `tuple`). I'd like to create a compile-time constant "descriptor" for the tuple, which contains all of its members' offset in the tuple. This descriptor contains a function pointer for each tuple member too. If I'd create this descriptor by hand, it would look like this (for example):

```
struct Entry {
    int offset;
    void (*function)(void *member);
};

Entry descriptor[] = {
    { 0, &SomeType1::static_function },
    { 12, &SomeType2::static_function },
    { 20, &SomeType3::static_function }
};
```

The intention of this is that I could have a general function (which is not a template), which can use this descriptor to call a type-specific function on each tuple member:

```
void call(void *tuple, const Entry *entries, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        entries[i].function(static_cast<char *>(tuple)+entries[i].offset);
    }
}
```

(The reason of this solution instead of a templated `call` function is that `call` is actually a huge function in my real code, and `entry[i].function` calls cannot be factored out from it. I'd like to avoid massive code duplication.)

Comment: As your types do not have a http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType, I would highly doubt that you can calculate any offset without entering the realm of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jodocus: no problem, as I've said in the question, UB is fine in this case, if the code happens to work.

Comment: Consider using pointers to members instead of offsets.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
struct Entry {
    void* (*data_member_getter)(void*);
    void (*function)(void *member);
};

namespace details
{
    template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
    constexpr void* voidPGetter(void* tuple)
    {
        return &std::get<I>(*reinterpret_cast<Tuple*>(tuple));
    }

    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t I>
    constexpr MakeEntry()
    {
        using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>;
        return { &voidPGetter<I, Tuple>, &type::static_function };
    }

    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
    constexpr std::array<Entry, sizeof...(Is)>
    ComputeEntryHelper(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return {{MakeEntry<Is, Tuple>()...}};
    }
}

template <typename Tuple>
constexpt auto ComputeEntry()
{
    constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
    return details::ComputeEntryHelper(std::make_index_sequence<size>());
}
```

And then

```
void call(void* tuple, const Entry* entries, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        entries[i].function(entries[i].data_member_getter(tuple));
    }
}
```

So instead of offset, having a function to get the data.

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution! But I'd like to keep using offsets instead of function calls (because of the overhead of function calling - yeah I know it is not huge, but this `call` function is used a lot, so it needs to be as efficient as possible). (The reason I've described my original problem is people can see why I'd like to have compile-time offsets.)