# Why don't we have offsetof which works with all types (except types with virtual inheritance)?

Tags: c++

Currently, `offsetof` works only with standard layout types. However, I've never understood this limit. Sure, for types with virtual inheritance, `offsetof` cannot work. But for types without virtual inheritance, it could. I know, the standard allows non-standard layout types to have differing offsets of members for each instance. But, I've never heard of any compiler implementations which uses this. Why would it do something like this?

All the compilers I know, for types without virtual inheritance, offsets of members are compile-time constants.

So the question is:

- is there any compiler, for which offsets of members are not compile-time constants (for types without virtual inheritance)?
- why doesn't the committee relax the requirements of `offsetof`?

(I've read a lot of related answers here in stackoverflow, and discussions of this at various places, but I haven't found the reason of this).

Comment: I'm interested in how you would use the resulting offset. All uses I can think of are C-compatible.

Comment: @chris: look at this related question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327400/getting-compile-time-constant-offsetof-of-base-class-in-multiple-inheritance . `offsetof` can be useful not just interfacing with C code.

Comment: I'd really have to caution against the UB. There are so many things that can change to possibly break it in the future without you changing this piece of code.

Comment: @geza in the linked question your premise that function calls imply overhead is false. If the compiler can see all the code it will optimise away getter functions.

Comment: @RichardHodges: it doesn't see all the code intentionally. If it would, it would create a lot of versions of `call` function. And that's the whole point: avoiding this. But, I cannot make it see these functions, anyway. `call` is a low-level library code in a .cpp file.

Comment: This ties in with the standard's peculiar definition (or effective definition, based on the constraints of usage) of "region of storage", which needs not be contiguous. That supports virtual inheritance. But it's a far more general support for object scattering than required for virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Is there any compiler which doesn't use contiguous storage for a class (without virtual inheritance)?

Comment: @RichardHodges: `call`'s compiled code is several KB, and it is called from thousands of places, thousands of different type configurations. So templatizing this function would increase .exe size with several MB's.

Comment: @chris: yes, yes. Because of this, I've created an own implementation of `tuple`, which uses `char[]` as internal storage, and distributes this area for the elements, and uses placement new. This has the drawback that this `tuple` cannot be constexpr. But now, at least, I have constexpr `offsetof`, and this code is non-UB.

Comment: @geza, To keep `constexpr`, you could probably use an array of sum types. `std::variant` gets you partway there, being able to access elements via the same index as they are in the array. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to avoid the check in `std::get` that the index is actually the active alternative.

Comment: @chris: hmm, can `std::variant` be constexpr? Or do you mean something else for which this doesn't required?

Comment: Yup, `std::variant` does all the hard legwork to be constexpr-compatible. Unless we ever get constexpr `new`, that means [using unions](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-20/eggs.variant---part-ii-the-constexpr-experience). However, assignment and `emplace` are notably not `constexpr`.

Comment: @chris: Ah, I've presumed that `std::variant` cannot be `constexpr`, because I saw no way to implement it with C++14. But now I see that it is available in only C++17. So maybe C++17 comes with a new feature, so I can implement my `tuple` constexpr (without `std::variant`) using C++17 (I'll check out `std::variant`'s implementation). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I believe it's possible to provide a standard-compliant implementation in C++11. Eggs.Variant advertises C++11 support, too. The standard often lags behind a bit for these types of things. When we get new language features, it often takes a standard or two for the library to use them more broadly.

Comment: @chris: then it's interesting, how they did it without using placement new, and reinterpret_cast (as these are forbidden in constexpr). I'll definitely check this out tonight.

Comment: @geza: In a trivial sense all compilers, because all compilers add padding as necessary for performance. But a more practical interpretation is, can one have two or more unrelated objects partially or completely within some other object, without virtual inheritance? I think that can possible happen with ordinary inheritance when a compiler notices that it can leverage space left over by padding in a base class object.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: that's okay, but this still means that the offset of any member is a compile-time constant, doesn't it?

Comment: @geza, The author of the library had a couple articles on the variant. I linked it in my above comment.

Comment: @geza: For the in-practice, yes. It's a mystery.

Comment: does your question include members of reference type ? clearly such types may have non constant offsets in their object representations ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: No, it doesn't include (but actually, it could: all the implementations I know, reference member is just a pointer, so it could give back this pointer's offset - but I don't really care too much: I've never used reference members).

Comment: "but actually, it could" are you sure ? an instance of such a type of automatic storage may have the reference effectively 'collapsed' as far as I know, or at least, the resulting offset would be meaningless because the 'pointer' value may not be used at all ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: yes, but does it matter actually? It can be collapsed too, if it were a pointer instead of a reference. We're talking about types now, not actual instantiations. If this reference initialized in all constructors to the same self-member, then this reference could be omitted in all cases, so in this case, `offsetof` is meaningless. So if it is complex to design/teach/implement, we could say that `offsetof` doesn't support reference members. In practice, this doesn't matter too much. I've yet to find a case where reference members are actually useful...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: but relaxing rules for `offsetof` is useful. This issue comes up a lot of times. Plus, that would be good that we can create compile-time constants out of offsets of sub-objects in the case of multiple inheritance. I had to mimic the compiler to get these offsets in my  own  implementation of `tuple` because of this shortcoming.

Comment: honestly I'm sceptical, you want to extend offsetof essentialy to ease type-punning ( I suppose ), that in turn depends on non trival non portable assumptions anyway on any practical situation ( at least if you want to avoid UB, eg. aliasing rules, manipulating pointers portably, etc... ) ... I mean, you'll need to get dirty anyway, so who cares ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: actually, I need this in a practical situation, and no dirty things here (no type punning, no UB). Look at the link in my first comment here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arbitrary nature of this restriction was [discussed in July](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0545r0.html) by the committee.  It's not in the working paper yet, but I believe it will be relaxed (to this degree, at least) in C++20.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's good to hear that the committee deals with this issue. I don't really understand the "no virtual functions" limit: "However, it is possible that other implementations exist. For instance, an implementation could use another hidden field that would contain an offset to data members of the final class object". Is there an implementation like this? If there is not, why not allow to have virtual functions? I think there should be a stronger argument against virtual functions than "it is **possible** that other implementations exist".

Comment: @geza: If the language requires support for a feature that is incompatible with some implementation strategy, it _precludes_ that strategy, basically forever.  Caution is warranted even lacking a current exemplar implementation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you in general. But only in the case that one can argue about why this implementation strategy is good. If no one would implement non-compile-time-constant offsets (because it is not logical at all), then why keep this possibility? Are there any positive sides of non-compile-time offsets? Are there any C++ feature planned which could need non-compile-time offsets?

Comment: @geza: I'm not an implementer, but I suppose that one could in theory avoid padding by rearranging inherited members.  Meanwhile, the paper does mention extending the supported set further if a good use case is identified.

Answer (score 2):

Relax the requirements **to what**? `offsetof`is okay to use except when it gives incorrect results?

The way to access selected data members of a C++ object is with a **pointer to data member**.

Comment: "Relax the requirements to what?": to be able to use it for any types, which doesn't have virtual inheritance. Pointer to data member is not that flexible as offsets, so it is not a one for one replacement (you cannot use them with `void *`).

Comment: @geza -- you can't use `offsetof` with `void*`, either. `offsetof` is for C hacking, and it's appropriate there. Extending it to hacking C++ types that aren't valid in C is a big step, with very little or no justification.

Comment: I meant that after I have my offset, I can do: `static_cast<char*>(some_void_ptr)+offset`. This is more flexible than pointer to data members (you cannot offset a `void *` with pointer to data members). Please read this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327400/getting-compile-time-constant-offsetof-of-base-class-in-multiple-inheritance. This question about getting offsets to base classes in multiple inheritance, but the principle is the same. Can you recommend some C++'ish way to do this? As I see, using `offsetof` is the most efficient way.

Comment: @geza -- the way to get back type information that you've thrown away is to not throw it away.

Comment: Huhh? We all the time throw away type information to get back it later.

Comment: There is also no way to go from a regular pointer which you happen to know points to a member of some class, to a pointer to that class. With a better `offsetof` function, you could at least get the memory address, and from there it’s possible to work around compiler pointer optimizations to get a valid pointer.